# advanced xml filtering in the windows event viewer

Tags: xml, windows, xml-parsing, event-viewer, logfiles

I would like to use the advanced xml filtering feature in the windows event viewer.
We received 'ReadAttributes' Events (4663) and 'SYNCHRONIZE|ReadAttribute' Events (4656) when we open the document. This happen every second for every file to check the files for new input and can't be adjusted.

To reduce the log amount in a 2nd application I need the XML from the event viewer to filter these events.

In the second application we can see in the raw event that the Windows namefield is AccessList for both, the 4663 and the 4656 events.

I tried this, but it leads to zero events:

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Security">
<Select Path="Security">
*[System[(EventID='4663')]]
        and
*[EventData[Data[@Name='AccessList'] and (text='ReadAttributes')]]
</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
```

Could you help me find my mistake and tell me how to combine with the 4656 events.

Comment: Could you also post the code that makes use of the above query?

Comment: It will be used by the Windows event viewer as filter [link](https://imgur.com/FPSpxRf)

Comment: So you want to get events with IDs  4663 and 4656 (and exclude all the rest)?

Comment: I would like to filter for 4663 and 4656 events that contain ReadAttributes or SYNCHRONIZE|ReadAttributes in the AccessList field. I would like avoid to filter out all 4663 events.

Comment: Could you edit the question and clarify what is the exact expectation? e.g from events with ID 4663 only the ones with *ReadAttributes*, and from ID 4656 *SYNCHRONIZE|Readattribute* (if I got it correctly). Also, what is `@Name='AccessList'`? I don't have such events on my machine, could you also explain how to generate them, as *ReadAttributes* is not very clear (where it should be), or better could you share 2 event *XML* samples (at least the relevant parts, if they are too long)? By the naked eye, your query doesn't seem correct from the square brackets perspective.

Comment: I tried, hope this make it more logical.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't. I asked for a specific list of things, instead I got some additional info out of which most of it is irrelevant.